# Camera is not instance of THREE.Camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

My project is basically working, but is always throws this exception:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera.
render @ three.min.js:196
animate @ fehlersuchen.html:295
(anonymous) @ fehlersuchen.html:139
fehlersuchen.html:227 9 0
```

As you can see I use the three.min.js library and fehlersuchen.html is my html file where I tried it.

my script:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera;
var CANVAS_WIDTH = 900;
var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 500;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, CANVAS_WIDTH / CANVAS_HEIGHT, 1, 2000);
camera.position.set(5500, 5000, -550); 
animate();
function animate() {
     requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
     renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `fehlersuchen.html`?

Comment: `fehlersuchen`? This is German and means "search for the error"? @Kati0208 Since you are a student let me ask the following question: Is this a homework assignment :)? Anyway, when I copy your code to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aesbtc9h/), only one error pops up. Your scene is not defined. After adding it the runtime errors are gone:

Comment: I am very sorry but I think I am not allowed to post the whole code of my school project :(